# display uiAlert in ios xamarin project on exception not showing

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to display an alert when an exception occurs and bubbles up to the iOS project.Main

Now let's suppose I have an "Object variable not set exception" somewhere in the program

it bubbles to the MyApp.IOS project but no UI alert pops up!!

```
        public class Application
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                try
                {
                    UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                            ShowAlert("MyTitle", ex.ToString(), UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController); 
                        });
                    });

                }

            }
            public static UIAlertController ShowAlert(string title, string description, UIViewController controller)
            {
                UIAlertController alert = UIAlertController.Create(title, description, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

                alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (action) => { }));

                controller.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);

                return alert;
            }
        }
```

any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Does the app still running after exception occurred? Because it looks like the app is dead after that exception.

Comment: The app is dead after I process the alert. If that is the case apart from logging is there a way of showing the user a message or too late?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not possible catch the error and show the alert. Check the information about the native crash. And check the log files.

[How can I catch all crash exception in monotouch/ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985803/how-can-i-catch-all-crash-exception-in-monotouch-ios)

[image]